# How can I write this MSSQL database query?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a specific scenario in which I have to assign discounts applicable on some Car Leads based on some given rules of Permutation and Combination.

To explain in details, I have these two tables:

[Below table contains some raw data of all leads of vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuptY.png)

And:

[Below Table contains the Rules (Permutation and combination) for all discounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRz2T.png)

What I want is to get the best rule from Rules based on the maximum number of variables matches in Rules from Lead.

How can I write the SQL for this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. You need to make an effort to both provide useful information and demonstrate what you have tried. In particular, what does "best rule" mean? Next, stop posting images. Post a script that contains DDL and populates your objects with sample data. Lastly, describe in sufficient detail your expected output from your sample data.

Comment: I have used cross-apply but it is returning me multiple records against a lead

Comment: SELECT 
  LD.*,
  RD.[Discount]
 FROM 
  LeadData as LD     
  CROSS APPLY ( 
  
     SELECT  [Discount]  FROM [RuleDiscountTable] RD
       WHERE 
         LD.[Make] = RD.[Make] AND 
         (
           LD.[City] = RD.[City] OR  RD.[City] IS NULL
         )
     ) RD

Comment: ^ Please edit your existing attempt into the question, using the formatting tools provided.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ld.Make, ld.FuelType, MAX(p.Discount)
FROM LeadData ld
  LEFT JOIN Permutation p on (ld.City = p.City OR p.City IS NULL) AND (p.FuelType = ld.FuelType OR p.FuelType IS NULL) AND (ld.Make = p.Make)
GROUP BY ld.Make, ld.FuelType
```

Comment: I dont have the exact value in Discount column. It is actually a expression which evaluates to a value. I cannot directly make decision on Discount.

Comment: I have written value to explain only.

Comment: exchange Permutation with your RuleDiscountTable and you should be good to go

Comment: That I cannot, as number of variable might grow in future.